# Is it possible in sharepoint 2010 to get all the groups a user belongs to? (no code)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

what the title says. I am not the farm administrator so I guess i don't have access to the sharepoint power shell. I am allowed to use sharepoint designer though and I guess I can set up a webpart that executes code even though I have never done it. I am open to any solution.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get all the groups an user belongs to is by checking site permissions of that user 
like explained in the article below,

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/check-permissions-for-a-person-or-site-HA101794808.aspx#_Toc288817126

Once you enter the user name and check permissions, it will display all the group that user belongs to but you need to be part of the Owner group to enumerate other users' permissions this way.

Comment: Thank you for you answer msounthar.  
In my understanding, this method tells you only the groups that let you interact with the site from which you launch the command. If inheritance is cut and the group structure changes down the hierarchy, the new groups the user is in wouldn't show up.  
Are you aware of any other way to get, of all the groups I have access to in the collection, to which of them a user belongs?  
Thank you very much, your feedback is very much appreciated.